# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, solid

I want to upload a file to a solid container.

I took this code as an example.
https://github.com/jeff-zucker/solid-file-client/blob/master/docs/node-upload.md

The difference is that I use `solid-auth-fetcher` for authorization. The code looks like this

```
const auth = require('solid-auth-cli')
const fc = new SolidFileClient(auth)
await fc.copyFile("file:///home/m0nte-cr1st0/fasf.jpg", "https://dimadmytruk23.inrupt.net/fasf.jpg" )
```

The user is already logged in at the time of the file upload.

However, I am getting the following error.

```
polyfills.js:139 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at Function.setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at polyfills.js:139
    at patch (polyfills.js:141)
    at patch (graceful-fs.js:104)
    at Object.<anonymous> (graceful-fs.js:96)
    at Object../node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js (graceful-fs.js:373)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object../node_modules/solid-rest/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js (index.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object../node_modules/solid-rest/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js (index.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.<anonymous> (file.js:4)
    at Object../node_modules/solid-rest/src/file.js (file.js:214)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at setRestHandlers (index.js:10)
    at Object.fetch (index.js:33)
    at SolidFileClient.fetch (SolidApi.js:140)
    at SolidFileClient.get (SolidApi.js:155)
    at SolidFileClient.copyFile (SolidApi.js:515)
    at Transcription.tsx:53
```

The file is there. The path is correct.

Comment: As also answered [on the Solid forum](https://forum.solidproject.org/t/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-undefined/4139/2?u=vincent): I’m quite sure that you’re unable to refer to local files (e.g. `file://...`) from scripts running in the browser, which I’m assuming is the case for you judging by your use of React?

Comment: @Vincent yeah. Thnx. I also have a base64 blob of this file.